# Suggested edit stats page shows incorrect pagination

Tags: bug, pagination, suggested-edit-stats

On the Linguistics Stack Exchange, the [statistics page on suggested edits for a week](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?page=1&tab=all&filter=week) happens to contain right now exactly 50 entries.

It fits on one page, but at the bottom there is a link to a second page that is—unsurprisingly—empty. It shouldn't be there with 50 items in the list.